# Longest path in a undirected and unweighted tree - in python

Tags: python, algorithm

I am solving a problem in which I need to calculate the diameter of the tree.I know how to calculate that using  2 bfs first to find the farthest node then do second bfs using the node we found from  the first one.

But I am having difficulty to implement a very simple step - making a adjacency list (dict in case of python) from the input I have written a code to this but its not tidy and not the best can someone tell how to do this efficently

> **Input**
>
> The first line of the input file contains one integer N --- number of
>   nodes in the tree (0 < N <= 10000). Next N-1 lines contain N-1 edges
>   of that tree --- Each line contains a pair (u, v) means there is an
>   edge between node u and node v (1 <= u, v <= N).
>
> **Example**:
>
> 8
>
> 1 2
>
> 1 3
>
> 2 4
>
> 2 5
>
> 3 7
>
> 4 6
>
> 7 8

My code is :

```
def makedic(m):
    d = {}
    for i in range(m):
        o, p = map(int, raw_input().split())
        if o not in d and p not in d:
             d[p] = []
             d[o] = [p]
        elif o not in d and p in d:
             d[o] = []
             d[p].append(o)
        elif p not in d and o in d:
            d[p] = []
            d[o].append(p)
        elif o in d:
            d[o].append(p)
           # d[p].append(o)
        elif p in d:
            d[p].append(o)
    return d
```

Here is how I implemented bfs:

```
def bfs(g,s):
    parent={s:None}
    level={s:0}
    frontier=[s]
    ctr=1
    while frontier:
        next=[]
        for i in frontier:
            for j in g[i]:
                if j not in parent:
                    parent[j]=i
                    level[j]=ctr
                    next.append(j)
        frontier=next
        ctr+=1
     return level,parent
```

Comment: please fix indentation.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre sorry for that .I did that in a hurry

Comment: Your input is inconsistent: it has 8 nodes, not 7.

Comment: @trincot made the correction

Comment: @johnsmith, the graph seems undirected from the problem statement, I believe.

Comment: yes it is an undirected tree

Comment: anyone knows a better way to do this ??

Comment: @johnsmith My answer is correct. I have implemented a lot of graph algorithms in competitive programming. That's the way to do it. Also your BFS seems very strange. I am not sure that it works

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2 I know yours is correct (I did not downvote your answer) but I am looking for a more elegant way to do this.And my bfs is correctly implemented you can check yourself

Comment: @johnsmith What do you mean by more elegant? You just have to put A in B's list and B in A's list. I am pretty sure there isn't any faster method.

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2  https://bitbucket.org/eightnoteight/spoj-solutions/src/b39d982505601f90922a25cfbb233fc5f7f3722c/pt07z_py3.py?at=master   see this link I am unable to make sense of his approach But it works

Comment: @johnsmith That approach is very inefficient regarding space complexity. It makes lots of unnecessary `list`s at the start of the code. Also you said you wanted to use `dict`. That approach is using `list`.

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2 yes its inefficient  in space complexity.But what is he doing with the input ?? Do you have asolution for this problem - http://www.spoj.com/problems/PT07Z/

Comment: It is basically the same with my code. But he is just using `list` instead of `dict`. First he makes a lot of lists then for each edge *(1-2)*: `A[0].append(1)`  and `A[1].append(0)`. Because he wants to use 0-index. I don't see which part of it you don't understand. Copy that part of the code and run it in your computer and then `print te` to see it for yourself.

Comment: @johnsmith are you getting time-limit?

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2 No I passed all the test cases in reasonable time

Comment: @johnsmith One last thing. Beware of `frontier=next`. It doesn't raise any specific problems in this case but you may run into some problems if you use this with lists that contain non-basic types or in languages that copies the whole list upon using `=` operator.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are unnecessary checks in your code. For each *A - B* edge you just have to put *B* in *A*'s adjacency list and *A* in *B*'s adjacency list:

```
d = {}
for i in range(m):
    u,v = map(int, raw_input().split())
    if u in d:
        d[u].append(v)
    else:
        d[u] = [v]
    if v in d:
        d[v].append(u)
    else:
        d[v] = [u]
```

According to the question every node has an index between *1* and *N* so you can use this fact and pre-populate the `dict` with empty lists. This way you don't have to check whether a key is in the `dict` or not. Also make the code a little bit shorter:

```
N = input()
d = { i:[] for i in range(1, N+1) }
for i in range(N):
    u,v = map(int, raw_input().split())
    d[u].append(v)
    d[v].append(u)
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using a **0** instead of **o** in makedic in first *elif* condition. Also made the correction for undirected graph.

```
def makedic(m):
    d = {}
    for i in range(m):
        o, p = map(int, raw_input().split())
        if o not in d and p not in d:
             d[p] = [o]
             d[o] = [p]
        elif o not in d and p in d:
             d[o] = [p]
             d[p].append(o)
        elif p not in d and o in d:
            d[p] = [o]
            d[o].append(p)
        elif o in d:
            d[o].append(p)
            d[p].append(o)
    return d
```

Comment: @johnsmith, run your program with these corrections. I think it will this time.

Comment: My program runs fine.But this is not the best way to do this

Comment: @johnsmith, c'mon dude, you mean "0 instead of o" was right. which you have corrected now in problem statement